# groovy implicit function parameter type conversion

Tags: groovy

Suppose there is a method like this: `someAPI(Integer)`. And I have a class

```
class MyClass{

    int toInteger(){
        0 // just for demo. the value will be generated on the fly
    }


    public <T> T asType(Class<T> c){
        0 // just for demo. the value will be generated on the fly
    }
}

MyClass myClass
someAPI(myClass as Integer) // OK but it's more like groovy than DSL
someAPI(myClass) // This is what i want, but it gives me an error: method not found.
```

How can I let groovy cast it for me automatically? Of course `someAPI()` is not mine to modify.

Comment: if the answer helped you, please make sure to "accept" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `someApi` method must exist in a class or interface. Supposing the class or interface is called `MyOtherClass`, then you can do this:

```
class MyOtherClass {
    void someAPI(Integer i) {println "I is $i"}
}

MyOtherClass.metaClass.someAPI = { i ->
    delegate.someAPI(i as Integer)
}


class MyClass {
    int toInteger() { 22 }
    def asType(Class c) { 22 }
}
```

Now, this works:

```
// this prints "I is 52" as expected because Strings can be cast to Integers
new MyOtherClass().someAPI("52")

// prints "I is 22", which is what MyClass returns when cast to Integer
new MyOtherClass().someAPI(new MyClass())

// Integers will work as expected, prints "I is 77"
new MyOtherClass().someAPI(77)
```

What I did was path the metaClass of the type which owns the `someAPI` method which I want to make accept anything... notice that I added a new `someAPI` to it which takes an untyped argument...

I implemented the new version of `someAPI` by *delegating* to the actual implementation after casting the argument to `Integer`, which is what you were trying to do.

This only works from Groovy code, of course.